# Clion code generation greyed out

Tags: c++, clion

I used to be able to use code generation in CLION to instantly generate getters/setters. However I recently found out that the generate button is greyed out. If i press ALT+INSERT now, i get the new tab to create a new file or c++ class. Any idea on how to regain the generate function?

Not sure if important but i'm using it on Windows with MinGW and I can still compile and run programs without any issues.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. The fix for me was to add the new class header/source to my CmakeLists.txt file. Once the class is added to the project, then options were no longer greyed out and the code generation functionality returned.

Comment: Thanks! I was using a make file and the terminal instead of using Clion to run the code so i forgot to update the CmakeList.txt file.